# python socketio.start_background_tast stunk handdle message

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

As Im going to using flask.socketio to build a project , I found something wrong, the code are as follows

```py
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    if 'self' in message:
        flag = 1
        @copy_current_request_context
        def movingcamera():
            global flag, status
            print('Start moving')
            while flag:
                GPIO.output(3, move[status][0])
                GPIO.output(2, move[status][1])
                if status == 2:
                    break
        socketio.start_background_task(target=movingcamera)

@socketio.on('moving')
def handle_moving(message):
    global status
    if 'up' in message:
        print('Got up message')
        status = 1
        time.sleep(2)
        status = 0
    elif 'down' in message:
        print('Got down message')
        status = -1
        time.sleep(2)
        status = 0
    elif 'mid' in message:
        status = 2
```

the code above is about control a mechine and got control message through sockerio.As I send 'self' to backend, it start work, howerver ,after that ,whatever I sent wasn't process anymore.
my operates are as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZzR2.png)
First I send 'moving' 'up' , the backend got the message and print 'Got up message'.Second I Send 'message' 'move' to start the mechine , the backend got the message and print 'recieved message:self', After that , whether how I send 'moving' or 'message' , it con't successfully process it and give me a reply .

I wonder if there are something wrong of my code or my operate. Or it's because of the 'socketio.start_background_test function'?

Comment: Are you using an asynchronous framework here? They are very likely incompatible with your hardware control functions. I suggest you use the threading async mode to avoid issues with your hardware library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why start_background_task stunk is 'while 1', maybe because of the time piece was fully spend in this while loop. So ,just adding a "socketio.sleep(0.5)" in the while loop can solve this problem easily.Just like the code as follows:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    if 'self' in message:
        flag = 1
        @copy_current_request_context
        def movingcamera():
            global flag, status
            print('Start moving')
            while flag:
                GPIO.output(3, move[status][0])
                GPIO.output(2, move[status][1])
                socketio.sleep(0.5)
                if status == 2:
                    break
        socketio.start_background_task(target=movingcamera)

@socketio.on('moving')
def handle_moving(message):
    global status
    if 'up' in message:
        print('Got up message')
        status = 1
        socketio.sleep(2)
        status = 0
    elif 'down' in message:
        print('Got down message')
        status = -1
        socketio.sleep(2)
        status = 0
    elif 'mid' in message:
        status = 2
```